# Lines transferred from main memory to Cache

Tags: c, memory, cache

I'm studying Cache memories and I would like to know exactly how the lines are transferred from memory to cache.
Supposing I have a 32-bit machine with a 16kB directly mapped cache and 8 words per line. If the cache still is empty, if I run:

```
volatile int* b= NULL;
for (register int=0; i<5; *a+=512) 
  *b=*a;
```

Exactly how many lines are being transferred to the cache? 5 lines (5 iterations of the cycle)? Only 1 line (last iteration of the cycle)?
Can someone please clarify me this?
Thank you!

Comment: Probably none, since I'd expect a segfault on the first iteration, once you finally get that through the compiler.